# Trying to log command history but shell script not working

Tags: linux, bash

Hi I am trying to log down all commands input into a shell session by using the following shell script `cmdlog.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

tail -f $HISTFILE | while read cmdline; do echo "$USER: $cmdline" >> /home/user/cmdhistory; done &
```

When I run the shell script followed by an echo command:

```
./cmdlog.sh
echo hello
```

The echo command is not logged to /home/user/cmdhistory. However if I manually typed the command in the terminal followed by the echo command:

```
tail -f $HISTFILE | while read cmdline; do echo "$USER: $cmdline" >> /home/user/cmdhistory; done &
echo hello
```

The echo command is logged to /home/user/cmdhistory.
I don't understand why the tail statement works on the terminal but not in the shell script.

Note: I've added the line PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a' to .bashrc so any new command is reflected in the history immediately.

Comment: Check if `$HISTFILE` is set in your script. Explain what "does not work" means exactly. Run the script with `-x` to see each command as it is executed. NB: don't use `while read` for this, but simply `tail -f … | sed 's/^/'"$USER: "'/' >> yourfile`

Comment: ```$HISTFILE``` is a environment variable that holds the name and location of your Bash history file, so no need to set it in the script. Edited question to explain what "does not work" means.

Comment: I think you want to run `./cmdlog.sh &`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the linux "**script**" command to achieve that.  Also, more detailed response [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200637/save-all-the-terminal-output-to-a-file).

To expand on my earlier comment, here is proof that the current session's history is not stored in the ~/.bash_history file:

```
ericthered@OasisMega1:/WORKS$ echo "History Test Command"
History Test Command
ericthered@OasisMega1:/WORKS$ tail ~/.bash_history
vi junk_41.sh
./junk_41.sh
./junk_41.sh --staff
./junk_41.sh --threshold 3
./junk_41.sh --threshold 1
./junk_41.sh --threshold 2
./junk_41.sh --threshold 2 --correlation
./junk_41.sh --threshold 2 --correlations
./junk_41.sh --threshold 2 --correlations --staff
sync
ericthered@OasisMega1:/WORKS$
```

If the current session was immediately added to that history file, you would see the **echo** command, **which is not showing** as the last command entered, as you seem to be expecting.

If you want the current session history and the $HISTORY file to form a continuous stream, you could try sourcing the following into your bash where you need that continuous history, assuming there are no parallel terminals with commands not yet logged in the $HISTORY file.

```
    ####   This should be sourced by bash shell
    ####!/bin/bash

Indent=`history | head -1 |
awk '{
    pos=index( $0, $2 ) ; 
    print pos-3 ;
}' `

(
    tac ~/.bash_history |
    awk -v indent="${Indent}" 'BEGIN{
        line=0 ;
        printf("##################### Boundary Line #####################\n" ) ;
    }
    {
        line-- ;
        printf("%"indent"d %s\n", line, $0 ) ;
    }' | tac

    history
)
```

Be aware that if you have specified a **HISTSIZE** value (not HISTFILESIZE), any command that goes past that max value **is lost**, meaning it does not get bumped into the HISTFILE, so you have gaps in history.  A good explanation of that is available [here](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/history-command).

Comment: My question is why isn't the shell script file working. What's wrong with the tail statement in the shell script file?

Comment: History for the live session is not part of the stored ~/.bash_history file.  It is appended to that hidden file only during the closing of the terminal session.  It also only does that for each terminal individually.  The command history that is appended is as a batch, not sequenced by historical timing, so commands from session B closed before session A, might contain commands entered after those of session A, but are registered earlier in the ~/.bash_history because that session closed first.  That does make reviewing the history file a bit confusing, since three are no session delimiters.

Comment: Regarding this, I've already added the line PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a' to .bashrc file, so any new command will immediately be appended to end of .bash_history when the new command finished. This is why I said that entering the tail statement directly in the terminal works. But I don't understand why the tail statement does not work when placed in a script.

Comment: Scripts that start with shebang open their own bash session, independant of the parent.  They don't have access to that parent's live command session.  The "-a flag", from what I understand is a single-shot "bump", not a toggle switch.  For that reason, while I don't know the how of doing it, I believe you need to implement the function to redirect all session command line capture/replication/storage into a file by some function that is loaded into the session with .bashrc-local .  Maybe that is where "script" could be loaded to suit your needs.